# Client Error while retrieving userinfo from Keycloak using Python

Tags: python, keycloak

Using Keycloak with python and flask for identity and access management.

here's the part of the code where the issue occurs:

```
from keycloak import Client
app = flask(__name__)
kc=Client()

.
.
.

app.route('/login')
def login():
    .
    .
    .
    access_token = kc.access_token
    userinfo = kc.fetch_userinfo(access_token) #the main issue
    session['user'] = userinfo

    return jsonify(userinfo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

so with the "userinfo" part, the error occurs saying:
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/linkedin_login/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo

if you have experience with keycloak, do you know if anything has to be altered to authorize in the use of userinfo in keycloak?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if your Client() from Keycloak is a KeycloakAdmin instance
(i'm using https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/ )
then the error probably comes from trying to access user information using administration credentials.

if your Client() is a KeycloakOpenID again from (https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/ ) then it might be a permission problem. You can check in the keycloak interface that the User you set up has Role Mapping>realm-management>realm-admin set (or something equivalent depending of the rights you want to give him).

in any case, a very usefull documentation can be found at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html

last and this might be off-topic but if you plain to access specific custom fields from the user infos, the Client Scopes panel will help you add them.